# Hangman Program(Repeated Letters)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

Okay so I have this practice for my programming class and we were asked to make a hangman game as you can see. All of the program works fine except for one thing: when a word has a letter repeated more than once, the program accepts one time only and then disregards it for the others. I think the problem is in the **setLetter** method. Its job is to replace the dashes with the letters. When I run the program and input the letter the second time around, it does tell me that it is a correct guess but it doesn't replace the dash with the letter.

Any help would be very appreciated! 
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {  

public static void main(String [] args) {

    // word list
    String [] hangmanList = {"accelerate", "achieve", "able", "microscope", 
            "thumb", "wonderful", "yard", "wood", "lemon", "favorite", "decide", "circular", 
            "broke", "elephant", "funny", "hamburger", "leg", "job", "lighthouse", "mother", 
            "notebook", "puzzle"};



    int allowedGuesses = 7;  

    String secretWord=pickRandomWord(hangmanList);        
    System.out.println(secretWord);

    char[] correctGuesses = new char [secretWord.length()];      


    for (int i=0; i<correctGuesses.length;i++){
        correctGuesses[i]= '-';
    }


    char [] incorrectGuesses= new char [20]; 



    int mistakeCount = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 



    for (int i=0; mistakeCount<allowedGuesses;i++){
        if (checkWinner(correctGuesses)!=true){

        printGallows(mistakeCount); 

        System.out.println("\n ");

        for (int j=0;j<correctGuesses.length;j++){
            System.out.print(correctGuesses[j]);
        }

        System.out.print("\nWrong guesses: ");
        for (int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(incorrectGuesses[j]);
        }


        System.out.print("\nPlease guess a letter: ");
        char a = input.next().charAt(0);; 


        boolean letterFound = false;         
        letterFound = matchFound(a,secretWord); 


        if (letterFound) {

           setLetter(a ,secretWord, correctGuesses); 
           System.out.println("-== correct guess! ==-");
        }
        else {

           incorrectGuesses[i]=a;

           mistakeCount++; 

           System.out.println(":(:(:( Oops! that is incorrect...");
        }   

    }
        else break; 

    }



    System.out.println("\n********************************************");
    System.out.println("The secret word was: " + secretWord);

    if (checkWinner(correctGuesses)) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you won!");
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Better luck next time!!!");
        printGallows(mistakeCount);             
    }


}       


private static boolean checkWinner(char[] correctGuesses) {
    boolean isWinner=false;

    for (int i=0; i<correctGuesses.length;i++){
        if (correctGuesses[i]!= '-') isWinner=true;
        else isWinner=false; 
    }

    return isWinner;
}


public static boolean matchFound(char guess,String secretWord) {
    char [] letters = secretWord.toCharArray(); 
    for (int i=0; i<letters.length;i++){

        if (guess == letters[i]) {
            return true ;
        }
    }
    return false;        
}


public static boolean setLetter(char guess,String secretWord, char[] correctGuesses) {

    char [] letters = secretWord.toCharArray(); 
    int guessed=0; 
    for (int i=0;i<letters.length;i++){

        if (guess==letters[i]){
            guessed++; 
        }

        if (guessed>0){
            correctGuesses[i]=letters[i]; 
            return true; 
        }

        else if (guess==0){
            correctGuesses[i]=letters[i]; 
            return true; 
        }
    }

    return false;        
}



private static void printGallows(int mistakeCount) {

    if (mistakeCount==0){
        System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__"); }

          else if (mistakeCount==1){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__"); }

          else if (mistakeCount==2){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__");}

          else if (mistakeCount==3){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  | \\|\n  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__");}

          else if (mistakeCount==4){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  | \\|/\n  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__");}

          else if (mistakeCount==5){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  | \\|/\n  |  |\n  |\n  |\n__|__");}

          else if (mistakeCount==6){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  | \\|/\n  |  |\n  | /\n  |\n__|__");}

          else if (mistakeCount==7){
          System.out.print("  ____\n  |  |\n  |  O\n  |  |\n  | \\|/\n  |  |\n  | / \\ \n  |\n__|__");}

}


private static String pickRandomWord(String[] dictionary){
    String secretWord=null;

    Random r = new Random (); 

    secretWord = dictionary [r.nextInt(dictionary.length)];     

    return secretWord;
}

}   // end of Hangman class
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, problem is in setLetter method. You are returning true on first letter match. My solution would be

```
    public static boolean setLetter(char guess, String secretWord, char[] correctGuesses) {

    char[] letters = secretWord.toCharArray();
    int guessed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (guess == letters[i]) {
            guessed++;
            correctGuesses[i] = letters[i];
        }
    }

    return guessed != 0;
}
```